# Creating a Full screen Overlay Navigation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to get a full screen navigation overlay to work on iPad sizes etc. I'm using bootstrap 3, and what I want is when the user gets the burger menu, and they click it, it will cause a full screen overlay such as this example: 
Here [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay2)

I for some reason cant get it to work on my code and I am wondering if its because of my bootstrap classes or what?

HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " id="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#myNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"><img alt="" src="Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#section1">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section2">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section3">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section4">Me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section5">Hobbies</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section6">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me get this to work when it goes to iPad sizes on 768 screens.

Comment: well you seem to have the solution in the link you shared. There is some javascript in there. Add it and adapt it to your classes/id-s

Comment: @MihaiT yes i know this and i have tried so, but i cant seem to get it to work at all and this is why i posted on here to see if someone can get it to work so i can see why

Comment: First of, you dont have an `overlay` element in your HTML, meaning that any javascript you might use, won't change anything. Add an element with the `overlay` class and the respective css given from your link and I guess it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .overlay {
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
            overflow-y: hidden;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .overlay-content {
            position: relative;
            top: 25%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .overlay a {
            padding: 8px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 36px;
            color: #818181;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .overlay a:hover,
        .overlay a:focus {
            color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .overlay .closebtn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            right: 45px;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " id="section1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#myNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">
                    <img alt="" src="Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse overlay" id="myNavbar">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right overlay-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section1">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section2">About Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section3">Skills</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section4">Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section5">Hobbies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#section6">Contact Me</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("button").on("click", function () {
            $("#myNavbar").css("height", "100%");
        });
        $("#myNavbar a").on("click", function () {
            $("#myNavbar").css("height", "0%");
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Try this saving as a HTML File and link bootstrap files properly. The thing you were missing was overlays. I used the same overlays from your link.